Implement dbcontext in two separate layers
I implement clean architecture and I don't want to reference my data layer from the host layer and use HostDbContext (DesignTimeDbContext) for migration only and my DataDbContext for connecting to my database like as abp Framework.
This is my data layer dbContext:
namespace EntityCore.Data
{
    public class MainApplicationDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public MainApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<MainApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Movie> Movies { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Movie>(b =>
            {
                b.ToTable("MoviesDBO");
                b.HasIndex(t => t.Id);
                b.Property(t => t.Name).IsRequired();
            });
        }
    }
}

This is my HostDbContext:
namespace MoviesHost.efCore
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }
    }
}

This is the DesignTimeDbContext config:
namespace MoviesHost.efCore
{
    public class ApplicationContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
        {
            var configuration = BuildConfiguration();

            var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>() 
                .UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));

            return new ApplicationDbContext(builder.Options);
        }

        private static IConfigurationRoot BuildConfiguration()
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");

            return builder.Build();
        }
    }
}

But when I add a migration, the file is empty as shown here:
namespace MoviesHost.Migrations
{
    /// <inheritdoc />
    public partial class initDatabase : Migration
    {
        /// <inheritdoc />
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
        }

        /// <inheritdoc />
        protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
        }
    }
}


Don't do that. DbContext is a multi-entity Unit-of-Work. It's not a database connection, driver or model. It doesn't need to be wrapped in low-level CRUD classes. like as abp FrameWork that product is full of very bad practices with code only used to check some "best practices" checklists, whether they're needed or not.

Why are you trying to create separate DbContexts for the application and migrations in the first place? Migrations are used to create the database used by the application's context. When that fails, it's because EF migrations can't handle the complexity of the real database (eg tables used by multiple applications, using features or security rules that can't be represented in EF Migrations, views, triggers etc). In that case you need proper database migration scripts and tools instead of ORM tools.

Whilst you can use multiple DbContext objects in your applicaiton, splattering the contexts throughout your application layers contravenes clean architecture.

If you want to, you can hide aspects of a single context behind multiple interfaces. The context itself should know about all tables.

Your migration file is empty because the ApplicationDbContext lacks database model configurations in its OnModelCreating method. To resolve this issue, you can centralize your model configurations using an extension method and apply this method in both MainApplicationDbContext and ApplicationDbContext. You can use the steps below:
1. Create an Extension Method
Create an extension method to configure your database models:
// EntityCore.Data/ModelBuilderExtensions.cs

using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Volo.Abp;

namespace EntityCore.Data
{
    public static class ModelBuilderExtensions
    {
        public static void ConfigureMovies(this ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            Check.NotNull(builder, nameof(builder));

            builder.Entity<Movie>(b =>
            {
                b.ToTable("MoviesDBO");
                b.HasIndex(t => t.Id);
                b.Property(t => t.Name).IsRequired();
            });
        }
    }
}

2. Update MainApplicationDbContext
Use this extension method in MainApplicationDbContext:
// EntityCore.Data/MainApplicationDbContext.cs

using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace EntityCore.Data
{
    public class MainApplicationDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public MainApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<MainApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Movie> Movies { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.ConfigureMovies();
        }
    }
}

3. Update ApplicationDbContext
// MoviesHost.efCore/ApplicationDbContext.cs

using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using EntityCore.Data;

namespace MoviesHost.efCore
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.ConfigureMovies();
        }
    }
}

In this case, separating the dependency doesn't make much sense. If you still want to separate it, you can write your extension methods in a common dependency.
